# Problems with IMac Ventura and Logic Pro X

Tags: ventura

I downloaded Ventura 13.0 and now Logic Pro X is almost useless.  Track bar doesn't move, imports don't load correctly, and a number of other quirks.  Contacted Apple and was told they take a look and be back to me in couple of days.  Does anyone else have these problems and have they found a fix???

Comment: I'm in a huge FB group [180k members] for Logic & so far there's a 50/50 split of people saying how marvellous it is vs those who think it's a disaster. [tbh, this is the same every year] There seems to be no consensus on "what failed" as yet, or how to fix it. You'll just have to pull all your plugins out & then add them back slowly & see where it fails. Personally, I'd never dream of being an early adopter for any professional application such as Logic or FCP. Let other people bug test it for 6 months first. [btw, there's no 'X' any more, it's been just Logic Pro since Big Sur]

Comment: Has there been an update of Logic for Ventura? I can't see one in the App Store; mine is version 10.7.4, dated April of this year. You may have to wait a couple of days.

Comment: @benwiggy - no. Apple seems to assume it will still work to spec… but they never test with a couple of hundred random 3rd party plugins, or for people with plugs on one drive, sample libraries on another, projects on a third, etc…